# how can i pass value to a running form

Tags: winforms, c#-3.0

I have 2 forms : Form1 and Form2
Form1 start running with Application.Run()

and Form1 have a datagridview if user Start Edit the DataGridView
i run Form2 like this in CellBeginEdit event

```
Form2 addStock = new Form2(productNo, stockString, this);
addStock.Activate();
addStock.Show();
```

After Form2 finish the task, When i click a button on Form 2 i want to get value return to Form1 and show in the DataGridView on Form1 and close the Form2

i tried to pass the Form1's object 
Form2 addStock = new Form2(productNo, stockString, **this**);

but on Form2 i can't access the Form1's DataGridview with that object

how can i do to accomplish this?

Comment: "but on Form2 i can't access the Form1's DataGridview with that object"  Change the Modifiers() property of the DataGridView to Public.  If you want to maintain some semblance of OOP-ness, expose the DataGridView thru a Public Property instead.

Answer (score 1):

what i suggest made a custom class and make some static members and when you are navigating to form2 jux check them.

```
class CustomClass
{

      public static int ProductNo;
      public static string StockString;
}
```

//these are call to form2 from form1

```
  CustomClasss.ProductNo=12; //some value
  CustomClass.StockString="Some Value";


   Form2 addStock = new Form2();
   addStock.Activate();
   addStock.Show();
```

now call these custom class members in form 2 and validate according to ur need..

like

```
if(CustomClass.ProductNo==2 && CustomClass.StockString=="Some String")
{
    //do something
}
```

Hope it helpx..

Answer (score 0):

Add `public properties` to Form2. After finishing the computation whatever you are doing within Form2 set the values to those properties. Now these values are accessible within From1 with the same From2 instance you have created to show the Form2.

Now within From1 access those property values of Form2.

```
Form2 addStock = new Form2(productNo, stockString, this);
addStock.Activate();
addStock.Show();

//Reading the property value of Form2
string stockValue = addStock.StockStringProperty;
```